# Ccombine test with null and undefined vars

Tags: javascript

When I debug this part of code, I see in the console :

[image]

When I try to build a condition with these 2 vars , it never log 'hello'  :

```
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
    const urlToken = this.getTokenFromUrl();
    console.log('urlToken :', urlToken)
    console.log('token :', token)
    console.log('type of token :', typeof(token))
    
    // if(!token && !urlToken){
    // if((token && token !== null)  && urlToken === undefined){
    if (token === null && urlToken === undefined){
       

        console.log('Hello');
```

I know that sometimes JS is difficult with such conditions.

What is my problem ?

Comment: It looks like `token` is the string “null” which !== `null`.

Comment: Your console log shows token is a `String` value `null`. So `token === "null"` will work.

Comment: Comparison with `==` to either `null` or `undefined` is equivalent to comparing for either value.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Better to answer in an *answer* than a comment. Nice catch. Most consoles put quotes around strings, but we can see this one doesn't from the last line, so again, nice one.

Comment: @Pointy - But in this case, the value is `"null"`, so... :-) Edit: Ah, you mean the code block...

Comment: Yes that's why I added the note as a comment, for the betterment of casual viewers in future days.

Comment: @ Dom - This is one reason why rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, I always recommend *turning on the lights* using the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE. Hopefully the debugger would show the values more clearly than this particular console does.

Comment: @ all : I have understood my mistake : token is a string, even if chrome displays it without quotes. And if I do token === "null", it works. Thanks a lot for your answers (I spent 2 hours on this problem). MERCI

Answer (score 0):

Your token is a string with the value of "null". So your check is failing. Changing it to `token === 'null'` would fix your code.